# Copy text and binary files with one function?

Tags: c, file-io

I have two functions. One copies text files which uses the `"r"` and `"w"` modes for reading and writing, and one that copies binary files which uses the `"rb"` and `"wb`" modes.

But if I were to use these functions, I have to determine first whether the file that I want to duplicate is a text or binary file. I want a solution that allows me to copy a file successfully without knowing previously the nature of the file. A single function that deals with this matter. Any ideas?

P.S : I noticed that `ctrl + c` copy is faster than my function, so tips to improve the speed of the function are also welcome.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void copyfile_txt(const char *inputfile, const char *outputfile);
void copyfile_bin(const char *inputfile, const char *outputfile);

int main(void)
{
    copyfile_txt("file_input.txt", "file_output.txt");
    copyfile_bin("ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso", "Ubuntu.iso");
    return 0;
}

long GetFileSize(FILE *fp)
{
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    long sz = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    return sz;
}
void copyfile_txt(const char *inputfile, const char *outputfile)
{
    static FILE *fp_I;
    static FILE *fp_O;

    fp_I = fopen(inputfile, "r");
    if (!fp_I) {
        perror(inputfile);
        return;
    }

    fp_O = fopen(outputfile, "w");
    if (!fp_O) {
        fclose(fp_I);
        perror(outputfile);
        return;
    }

    static int c;
    while ((c = getc(fp_I)) != EOF) {
        putc(c, fp_O);
    }
    fclose(fp_I);
    fclose(fp_O);
}
void copyfile_bin(const char *inputfile, const char *outputfile)
{
    static FILE *fp_I;
    static FILE *fp_O;

    fp_I = fopen(inputfile, "rb");
    if (!fp_I) {
        perror(inputfile);
        return;
    }

    fp_O = fopen(outputfile, "wb");
    if (!fp_O) {
        fclose(fp_I);
        perror(outputfile);
        return;
    }

    static int c;
    static long n;
    static long sz;

    n = 0;
    sz = GetFileSize(fp_I);

    while (n++ < sz) {
        c = getc(fp_I);
        putc(c, fp_O);
    }

    fclose(fp_I);
    fclose(fp_O);
}
```

Comment: Just copy the text file as a binary using `fread` and `fwrite` - its content is irrelevant.

Comment: Additionally you do not need to find the file size. You keep writing the number of bytes that were read, until the bytes read were 0. `while((bytes = fread(buf, 1, sizeof buf, fin)) > 0) { fwrite(buf, 1, bytes, fout); }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to make a special case of text files, copy all files as binary. This is what most file copying utilities do.

Note however that your binary file copying function has problems:

- There is no need to compute the file size, copying until you get `EOF` is correct and allows you to copy files larger than `LONG_MAX`.
- There is no need for static variables: using `static` variables makes your function fail if used from multiple threads.
- It would be useful to return a completion code.

Here is a simpler version:

```
int copyfile_bin(const char *inputfile, const char *outputfile) {
    FILE *fp_I;
    FILE *fp_O;

    fp_I = fopen(inputfile, "rb");
    if (!fp_I) {
        perror(inputfile);
        return -1;
    }

    fp_O = fopen(outputfile, "wb");
    if (!fp_O) {
        fclose(fp_I);
        perror(outputfile);
        return -1;
    }

    int c;
    while ((c = getc(fp_I)) != EOF) {
        putc(c, fp_O);
    }

    fclose(fp_I);
    if (fclose(fp_O) != 0) {
        perror(outputfile);
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To improve speed, you could increase the buffer sizes with `setvbuf()` or use `fread()` and `fwrite()` with a large allocated buffer.

For a faster inner loop, use this:

```
    size_t nr, size = 1024 * 1024;
    void *buffer = malloc(size);
    if (buffer != NULL) {
        while ((nr = fread(buffer, 1, size, fp_I)) > 0) {
            if (fwrite(buffer, 1, nr, fp_O) != nr) {
                fprintf(stderr, "write error: ");
                perror(outputfile);
                free(buffer);
                fclose(fp_I);
                fclose(fp_O);
                return -1;
            }
        }
        if (ferror(fp_I)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "read error: ");
            perror(inputfile);
            free(buffer);
            fclose(fp_I);
            fclose(fp_O);
            return -1;
        }
        free(buffer);
    } else {
        /* use the regular getc/putc loop */
        int c;
        while ((c = getc(fp_I)) != EOF) {
            putc(c, fp_O);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @machine_1: Adding error checking, logging and handling to those reads and writes isn't a bad idea as well ...

Comment: @alk: error checking on the write side is there already, I shall update for the read part, trying to tell read error from regular end of file.

Comment: Oh yes, the "high speed extension" brought the checking, sry, missed that.

Comment: i have a question: you use ```ferror``` to check for read errors, why have you not also used ```feof```? wouldnt it be sensible to also check for end of file errors too?

Comment: @programme3219873: `feof()` does not report an error, it returns non zero after a read API fails because it reaches the end of file, which is the expected behavior at the end of file anyway. `feof()` can be used to detect a premature end of file causing a read operation to fail, but when copying the file, reaching the end of file is intended.